# SOAP request through JMeter with authentication

Tags: web-services, soap, jmeter

I'm having trouble sending a JMeter SOAP request through HTTP Request element - 
Through SOAPUI I'm sending the request with the following properties:

[Authentication via SOAP](https://postimg.org/image/46lxsuij7/)

But I cannot receive a valid response when I try to add these username password. I've tried to place it in HTTP Header Manager/ in HTTP Authorization Manager, but with no luck. I receive either error:

> Response code: 404 Response message: Not Found

when placing this in the HTTP Authorization Manager and

> HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name

when placing the username and password in the header manager (with wss password type field, while in HTTP Authorization Manager there is not option like this).

What can I do to have a valid response from the server like I get in SOAPUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to replicate SoapUI request I would suggest just to record the request from the SoapUI via JMeter [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. In JMeter

   - File -> Template -> Recording -> Create
   - Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder -> Start
2. In SoapUI

   - File -> Preferences -> Proxy Settings
   - Host: localhost, Port: 8888
3. Enable proxy in SoapUI
4. Execute your request
5. Expand Thread Group -> Recording Controller in JMeter and observe the recorded request.

[image: JMeter Record SoapUI request]

You may also need to correlate timestamps using [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) check out [Take the Pain out of Load Testing Secure Web Services](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/take-pain-out-load-testing-secure-web-services) for details on bypassing different web services security in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, this solved my problem in general. But, do I have to use port 8888? Is port 8887 can be enough?

Comment: This is default port of JMeter's proxy, you can change it to whatever you want, just make sure that JMeter and SoapUI have the same proxy port

Comment: Great comment. Now I'm experiencing the following: Trying to Start again the script recorder results in 'could not create script recorder port in use' error (port 8888) - maybe it is related to ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA? And when I try to change the port in SoapUI for other than 8888 I have an error of Connection refused. What can I do? thanks

Comment: This question is out of the original discussion scope. Find a free port. Configure JMeter proxy to use it. Configure SoapUI to use the same port. If you don't know what application uses port 8888 and what port is free I would recommend looking for a less complicated job.